# Sed or awk after last colon?

Tags: bash, unix, sh

I am trying to print out the last couple of words after the last colon in this line:

```
Tue Jul 21 11:17:50 NetBoot046 jamf[1240]: Installation failed. The installer reported: installer: Package name is GarageBand
```

So the output would be `Package name is GarageBand`

Is there a way to sed out this part?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that the part you wish to "fix", does not contain a newline, i.e. you have only one line of input, or all of relevant text is contained in one line.

```
sed -e 's/.*://'
```

Comment: For completeness, `sed -e 's/.*: //'` will remove the space at the beginning to match the requested string exactly.

Comment: The option -e is unnecessary. It is if there are more than one expression. I would have written: `echo <text output> | sed 's/.*: *//'`

Answer (score 3):

Since a sed solution has been posted, here's one in awk:

```
<text output> | awk -F ":" '{print $NF}'
```

1. Make `:` your field separator
2. Print the last field.